# Using external CSS with <use> of SVG

Tags: css, svg

I'd like to create a svg sprite using `<symbol>` and `<use>` but I'd like to add an external CSS too...

My SVG :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style type="text/css">@import url(mycss.css);</style>
  <symbol id="cross" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path class="cross1" d="M17.1 5.2l-2.6-2.6-4.6 4.7-4.7-4.7-2.5 2.6 4.7 4.7-4.7 4.7 2.5 2.5 4.7-4.7 4.6 4.7 2.6-2.5-4.7-4.7"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

My HTML :

```
<svg><use xlink:href="../images/sprites.svg#cross"></use></svg>
```

My CSS :

```
#cross > .cross1{
  fill: red;
}
```

The `fill` property doesn't work...

Comment: did you tried with `#cross path{...}` ?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work too...